# Почему sorted() не полностью сортирует список?

Tags: python

Часть задания проходит тесты, но последнее тест выдает не полностью отсортированный список. Задание с сайта:
https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/sets/problems/sets_intersection/

```
a=set(input().split())
b=set(input().split())
c=(set(a.intersection(b)))

#print(a)
#print(b)
#print(c)

c=list(c)
c=sorted(c)
#c.sort()
print(" ".join(c))
```

Comment: Что значит "**не полностью** отсортированный список"? Приведите пример.

Comment: множества1 и 82 54 91 100 70 33 88 14 52 48 56 20 63 16 22 23 30 8 84 75 45 95 51 98 4 86 78 24 5 77 76 18 97 10 17 66 2 43 61 53 21 69 19 39 7 11 72 40 79 57 68 96 80 71 67 13 99 83 35 27 28 73 36 6 25 55
Множество2: 10 44 77 90 43 75 25 24 5 21 71 70 83 68 18 92 81 57 27 67 48 6 87 36 64 49 19 72 62 29 22 82 7 17 1 73 54 30 9 66 61 95 55 28 86 39 3 42 74 60 93 2 52 78 34 51 32 94 11 37 26 23 69 58 35 14 84

Выдает не отсортированный список: 10 11 14 17 18 19 2 21 22 23 24 25 27 28 30 35 36 39 43 48 5 51 52 54 55 57 6 61 66 67 68 69 7 70 71 72 73 75 77 78 82 83 84 86 95

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема в том, что input.split() возвращает список строк, а не чисел. После чего вы сравниваете эти строки в надежде получить сортировку чисел, а это не одно и то же.

Это можно увидеть на предоставленном вами сайте при пошаговом выполнении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Достаточно при парсинге введенной строки привести каждую подстроку к числу, в данном случае, видимо, к int:

```
a=set([int(x) for x in input().split()])
b=set([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

В конечном счете получаем следующий код:

```
a=set([int(x) for x in input().split()])
b=set([int(x) for x in input().split()])
c=(set(a.intersection(b)))

c=list(c)
c.sort()
print(*c)
```

---

### UPD

**Почему на некоторых тестовых данных изначальный код работал верно?**

Все просто, в первых двух тестах пересечение двух списков не содержало цифры больше 9, т.е. подстроки состояли из одного элемента, сравнение таких строк происходит по их числовому представлению, будь то ASCII или любая другая кодировка. А вот сравнение строк с 2+ символами - совсем другая история, они сравниваются поэлементно + на результат этого сравнения влияет размер строки.

**Что такое *с?**

В данном случае эта операция распаковывает список в отдельные элементы, которые в конечном счете подставляются в `print()` в виде позиционных аргументов.

Comment: Спасибо за подбробный ответ и развернутое пояснение! Еще остался вопрос, почему в первых двух тестах проходил верный ответ. Ведь там тоже происходит сортировка списка строк? И что значит print(*c), не понятно *с, что делает эта операция?

Comment: @AlexSapsay, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно почему прошли 2 теста. А вот *с- все звучит как магия. Можно ли заменить *с на запись print(' '.join([str(i) for i in c])) . Да, оказывается можно. Ваша запись значительно компактнее. Но пока это не достижимое для меня понимание Кунг фу

Comment: @AlexSapsay, да на самом деле распаковка кортежей/списков - полезная и простая штука, погуглите "tutple unpacking" :)

Comment: Ок, попробую! выглядит конечно очень круто